# Can VSCode be extended with functionality to call functions exposed by a COM object

Tags: visual-studio-code, com

Probably easiest to explain my use case.  I'm looking for a text editor for transcription rather than coding.  BUT the key feature I need is the ability to extend the text editor with small "macro" snippets that can call a COM object interface.

In this case it would call a COM interface supplied with the audio playback tool that has functions to get the current timestamp, change to a different time in playback, turn channels on/off, jump forward/back, etc.

Practical example:
I press a shortcut key in VSCode
That triggers a macro of some kind
This macro instantiates a COM object for my player (we'll call that "myplayer")
The macro calls "myplayer.GetCurrentTimeStamp" which returns a timestamp as a value.
I format the output to get the time in h:mm:ss am/pm format.
The timestamp is inserted into my text file.

Possible?

Comment: what you can do is write a command line program that calls the COM API and saves the result in a temporary file, and have VSC read the content of that file and insert that in the editor, last step can be done with extension `Command Variable` (I will modify this extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an external program that will store the timestamp in a temporary file you can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) (v1.12) to read (part of) the file content and insert it in the editor.

Use the extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) to combine the 2 commands.

1. Define a task that runs the external command
2. Define a multi-command that calls the task and then `extension.commandvariable.file.contentInEditor`
3. Define a key binding that calls the multi-command

Add to **`.vscode/tasks.json`**

```json
    {
      "label": "get Timestamp",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "echo timestamp=2021-04-01 12:34 >/tmp/timequery.txt",
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
```

Add to **`.vscode/settings.json`**

```json
  "multiCommand.commands": [
    {
      "command": "multiCommand.insertTimestamp",
      "interval": 500,
      "sequence": [
        { "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
          "args": "get Timestamp"
        },
        { "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.contentInEditor",
          "args": {
            "fileName": "/tmp/timequery.txt",
            "key": "timestamp",
            "default": "Query failed"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Add to **`keybindings.json`**

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+F1", // or any other key combo
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { "command": "multiCommand.insertTimestamp" },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I was kind of hoping to avoid having to build an external program to store a timestamp in a temp file.  Seems kind of "janky" if you know what I mean.  Also, the timestamp in this use case would need to be reread from the target program at least once a second to be useful.

Comment: Actually I apologize.  I didn't think through your answer adequately.  I suppose I could build a script, perhaps powershell, that can call a comm object and write it to a text file when required.  Is there another way besides temporary text file that might make sense that VSC could also access?

Comment: @PeterDowling the clipboard, maybe even a socket if node.js can handle it